# Run and close child context from parent app

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-task

I'm using spring application builder to run child context application (spring Cloud task) from parent. I'm also passing running parent context to the builder of child application - it has DataSource bean defined and I want it to be used by task as well.

My problem is that when the child context is closed, all parent bean are also destroyed.
Am I doing something wrong?

How can I share beans from parent context with child and still keep them alive when the child context exits.

```
@Component
public class ClassInParentContext{

 @Autowired
 private ConfigurableApplicationContext parentAppCtx;

 @Autowired
 private DataSource ds; //this bean is defined in parent context and I want it to be passed to child but not to be disposed when the child context closes.

 public void onSomeEventInParentContext(){
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(com.app.child.Child.class)
            .parent(parentAppCtx)  
            .run(args); //this context is autoclosed by spring cloud task 
 }
}

@EnableTask
public class Child{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't describe your code. Post it.

Comment: @JBNizet, I've added the code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to `spring-cloud-task` team turns out that the parent context implicitly, forcibly and intentionally  closed when task ends.